# How to stop href inside on the same html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to stop href to a div on the same page i tried this but not working for the same page but is working for other page.

```
 <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"  class="surveydata">
```

This is my function

```
$("a.surveydata").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

But always go to my div with id tab2

Comment: May i ask why you do not remove it before rendering?

Comment: You could try adding: `return false;`

Comment: I want to check that the inputs have the data before sending to the div

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the href attribute from the  tag when the page load, like this:

```
$('a.surveydata').first().removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Providing code only answers does is not good quality response. Please read [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)